# .replaceWtih() jquery for link tag

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content.css">
```

with

```
<!--link commented out for this page only-->
```

using jquery `.replaceWith();`

This line of code is in the head tag. I been trying several different ways and so far it hasn't worked. I just need that one line of code to be replaced with the comment when a button is clicked.

This is what I wrote so far but it's not working the way I want it to.

```
$( "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content.css">" ).replaceWith( "<!--link commented out for this page only-->" );
```

Comment: Espace your double quotes inside the "link blahblah" string.

Answer (score 0):

You seem like you want to manipulate raw HTML content. However, you want to use a selector to target an element on the DOM as follows:

```
$( 'link[href="content.css"]' )
.replaceWith( "<!--link commented out for this page only-->" );
```

**NOTE**: Remember that this code runs once the DOM has loaded, and it quite possible that CSS would have loaded. Therefore, I am not sure that commenting out this line would unload the CSS from memory :(

Comment: and if I wanted to do it the other way around as well to go back to the original line of code?

Comment: That's a totally different question ... unfortunately, there's no selector for `<!-- ....... -->`.